# Replace a MatchCollection items from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string containing mathematical expression like:

```
strExpression= a+b+tan(a)+tan(b)+a+b
```

I want to replace this expression with values of a and b(say a=10,b=20) so that it become:

```
10+20+tan(10)+tan(20)+10+20
```

But when I use `Regex.Replace` I get:

```
10+20+t10n(10)+t10n(20)+10+20
```

How can I replace the values of a and b at correct places.

I have filterd out MatchCollection object that contains:

```
{a},{b},{tan},{a},{tan},{b},{a},{b}
```

Comment: Can you show us the regex you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use word boundary `\b` before and after the variable name (e.g. `\ba\b` for variable `a` and `\bb\b` for variable `b`) to match the variable in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Use *boundary* `\b`:

```
\b    The match must occur on a boundary 
      between a \w (alphanumeric) and a \W (nonalphanumeric) character.
```

for example:

```
\b\w+\s\w+\b
```

result is

```
"them theme" "them them" in "them theme them them"
```

so that use:

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(\bb\b)", "20");
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(\ba\b)", "10");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string expression = "strExpression= a+b+tan(a)+tan(b)+a+b";
expression = Regex.Replace(expression, @"\ba\b", "10");
expression = Regex.Replace(expression, @"\bb\b", "20");
Console.WriteLine(expression);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to be more specific in your regex rather than just replacing the values. Here are some rules which describes whether a character captured is variable or not

1. Variable must have binary operator(+,-,*,/) and optinally spaces to its right(if start) ,to its left(if end) or on both side. It can also have paranethis around it if passed in function.
   So create a regex which satisfies these all conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can do with this:

[Regex Example](http://regexr.com?31hoq)

And then use the same way for `b` with replacement of `20`